# Clear all breakpoints in gdb

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I get into situations in gdb/ddd where there are too many breakpoints.

I want to disable or remove all of them at once, or all except for one. I find the ddd breakpoints menu confusing and unreliable. How can I do this with a gdb command?

Answer (score 46):

use `delete` command with no arguments; it can be abbreviated to `del` or `d`.

Answer (score 17):

> I want to disable or remove all of them at once, or all except for one.

Use `disable` (with no arguments) to disable all breakpoints, followed by `enable N`, where N is the breakpoint you want to keep.